# Upgrade kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:XXX" -> error: cannot find symbol

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio **3.2**, Gradle **4.6**

In my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = '8.8.1'
    ext.GLIDE_VERSION = '4.2.0'
    ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.2.41'
    ext.REALM_VERSION = '4.1.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$REALM_VERSION"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

In my app/build.gradle:

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2"
```

And my Android project success build and run.
Nice.

Now I upgrade to last version of plugins:

```
buildscript {
    ext.BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = '8.8.1'
    ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.2.71'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'

        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$REALM_VERSION"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"           
    }
}
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"
```

Project success build but when I run project I get error:

```
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
e: myproject\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\com\myproject\databinding\AdvertisingBinding.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  protected AdvertisingBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                               ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AdvertisingBinding
```

I try `Invalidate cache / Restart` but it not help.

Comment: same issue, not resolved yet

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue suddenly. A list of 'error: cannot access ...' pointing to import statements. Android Studio can find them without issue when using Command-B.